# CRC32 assembler function called from C console app

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to call asm function from external file in C code. It builds fine but the result is not as it's supposed to be. Instead of file checksum, I see some strange characters.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>

    extern "C" unsigned long __stdcall CRC32(size_t sizeOfFile, char buffer[]);


    int fsize(char* file) {
        int size;
        FILE* fh;

        fopen_s(&fh, file, "rb" );
        if(fh != NULL){
            if( fseek(fh, 0, SEEK_END) ){
                fclose(fh);
                return -1;
            }

            size = ftell(fh);
            fclose(fh);
            return size;
        }

        return -1; //error
    }

    void calculateChecksum(char * filename, char * checksum){
        FILE *file = NULL;

        unsigned long crc32;


        char hex[10];
        fopen_s(&file, filename, "rb" );
        size_t size = fsize(filename);
        char *buffer=(char*)malloc(size);
        fread_s(buffer,size,size,1,file);
        crc32=CRC32(size,buffer);
        int n = sprintf_s(hex,"%x",crc32);

        for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
            checksum[i]=hex[i];
        }
        fclose(file);
        file = NULL;
    }




    int main(){
        char checksum[8];
        calculateChecksum("B:\\secretMessageC#.txt",checksum);

        char hex[10];

        for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
            checksum[i]=hex[i];
            printf("%c",checksum[i]);
        }

        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

My external Assember code:

```
    .586
    .model flat, stdcall 
    .xmm
    .data
    .code
    CRC32 proc sizeOfFile:DWORD, file:DWORD
        push    esi
        push    ecx
        push    edx

        mov esi, file
        xor edx, edx
        or  eax, -1
        mov ecx, sizeOfFile

    CRC32_loop:
        mov dl, byte ptr [esi]
        xor dl, al
        shr eax, 8
        xor eax, dword ptr [crc32_table + 4*edx]
        inc esi
        dec ecx
        jnz CRC32_loop

        not eax

        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop esi
        ret
            CRC32 endp
    crc32_table dd 000000000h, 077073096h, 0EE0E612Ch, 0990951BAh, 0076DC419h, 0706AF48Fh, 0E963A535h, 09E6495A3h, 00EDB8832h, 079DCB8A4h
                dd 0E0D5E91Eh, 097D2D988h, 009B64C2Bh, 07EB17CBDh, 0E7B82D07h, 090BF1D91h, 01DB71064h, 06AB020F2h, 0F3B97148h, 084BE41DEh
                dd 01ADAD47Dh, 06DDDE4EBh, 0F4D4B551h, 083D385C7h, 0136C9856h, 0646BA8C0h, 0FD62F97Ah, 08A65C9ECh, 014015C4Fh, 063066CD9h
                dd 0FA0F3D63h, 08D080DF5h, 03B6E20C8h, 04C69105Eh, 0D56041E4h, 0A2677172h, 03C03E4D1h, 04B04D447h, 0D20D85FDh, 0A50AB56Bh
                dd 035B5A8FAh, 042B2986Ch, 0DBBBC9D6h, 0ACBCF940h, 032D86CE3h, 045DF5C75h, 0DCD60DCFh, 0ABD13D59h, 026D930ACh, 051DE003Ah
                dd 0C8D75180h, 0BFD06116h, 021B4F4B5h, 056B3C423h, 0CFBA9599h, 0B8BDA50Fh, 02802B89Eh, 05F058808h, 0C60CD9B2h, 0B10BE924h
                dd 02F6F7C87h, 058684C11h, 0C1611DABh, 0B6662D3Dh, 076DC4190h, 001DB7106h, 098D220BCh, 0EFD5102Ah, 071B18589h, 006B6B51Fh
                dd 09FBFE4A5h, 0E8B8D433h, 07807C9A2h, 00F00F934h, 09609A88Eh, 0E10E9818h, 07F6A0DBBh, 0086D3D2Dh, 091646C97h, 0E6635C01h
                dd 06B6B51F4h, 01C6C6162h, 0856530D8h, 0F262004Eh, 06C0695EDh, 01B01A57Bh, 08208F4C1h, 0F50FC457h, 065B0D9C6h, 012B7E950h
                dd 08BBEB8EAh, 0FCB9887Ch, 062DD1DDFh, 015DA2D49h, 08CD37CF3h, 0FBD44C65h, 04DB26158h, 03AB551CEh, 0A3BC0074h, 0D4BB30E2h
                dd 04ADFA541h, 03DD895D7h, 0A4D1C46Dh, 0D3D6F4FBh, 04369E96Ah, 0346ED9FCh, 0AD678846h, 0DA60B8D0h, 044042D73h, 033031DE5h 
                dd 0AA0A4C5Fh, 0DD0D7CC9h, 05005713Ch, 0270241AAh, 0BE0B1010h, 0C90C2086h, 05768B525h, 0206F85B3h, 0B966D409h, 0CE61E49Fh
                dd 05EDEF90Eh, 029D9C998h, 0B0D09822h, 0C7D7A8B4h, 059B33D17h, 02EB40D81h, 0B7BD5C3Bh, 0C0BA6CADh, 0EDB88320h, 09ABFB3B6h
                dd 003B6E20Ch, 074B1D29Ah, 0EAD54739h, 09DD277AFh, 004DB2615h, 073DC1683h, 0E3630B12h, 094643B84h, 00D6D6A3Eh, 07A6A5AA8h 
                dd 0E40ECF0Bh, 09309FF9Dh, 00A00AE27h, 07D079EB1h, 0F00F9344h, 08708A3D2h, 01E01F268h, 06906C2FEh, 0F762575Dh, 0806567CBh
                dd 0196C3671h, 06E6B06E7h, 0FED41B76h, 089D32BE0h, 010DA7A5Ah, 067DD4ACCh, 0F9B9DF6Fh, 08EBEEFF9h, 017B7BE43h, 060B08ED5h
                dd 0D6D6A3E8h, 0A1D1937Eh, 038D8C2C4h, 04FDFF252h, 0D1BB67F1h, 0A6BC5767h, 03FB506DDh, 048B2364Bh, 0D80D2BDAh, 0AF0A1B4Ch
                dd 036034AF6h, 041047A60h, 0DF60EFC3h, 0A867DF55h, 0316E8EEFh, 04669BE79h, 0CB61B38Ch, 0BC66831Ah, 0256FD2A0h, 05268E236h
                dd 0CC0C7795h, 0BB0B4703h, 0220216B9h, 05505262Fh, 0C5BA3BBEh, 0B2BD0B28h, 02BB45A92h, 05CB36A04h, 0C2D7FFA7h, 0B5D0CF31h
                dd 02CD99E8Bh, 05BDEAE1Dh, 09B64C2B0h, 0EC63F226h, 0756AA39Ch, 0026D930Ah, 09C0906A9h, 0EB0E363Fh, 072076785h, 005005713h
                dd 095BF4A82h, 0E2B87A14h, 07BB12BAEh, 00CB61B38h, 092D28E9Bh, 0E5D5BE0Dh, 07CDCEFB7h, 00BDBDF21h, 086D3D2D4h, 0F1D4E242h 
                dd 068DDB3F8h, 01FDA836Eh, 081BE16CDh, 0F6B9265Bh, 06FB077E1h, 018B74777h, 088085AE6h, 0FF0F6A70h, 066063BCAh, 011010B5Ch
                dd 08F659EFFh, 0F862AE69h, 0616BFFD3h, 0166CCF45h, 0A00AE278h, 0D70DD2EEh, 04E048354h, 03903B3C2h, 0A7672661h, 0D06016F7h
                dd 04969474Dh, 03E6E77DBh, 0AED16A4Ah, 0D9D65ADCh, 040DF0B66h, 037D83BF0h, 0A9BCAE53h, 0DEBB9EC5h, 047B2CF7Fh, 030B5FFE9h
                dd 0BDBDF21Ch, 0CABAC28Ah, 053B39330h, 024B4A3A6h, 0BAD03605h, 0CDD70693h, 054DE5729h, 023D967BFh, 0B3667A2Eh, 0C4614AB8h
                dd 05D681B02h, 02A6F2B94h, 0B40BBE37h, 0C30C8EA1h, 05A05DF1Bh, 02D02EF8Dh   
    end
```

Comment: You made the standard mistake of not describing what you expected to happen.  The result of a CRC32 are *bytes*, not characters.  Bytes are funny looking characters when they don't happen to map to an ASCII code.  They rarely do, odds are only 1 in 4.  A simple way to validate your program is to compare the result you get to the result of a known-good C implementation of CRC32, google knows lots of them.  If it doesn't match then keeping the C implementation is a good way to get this project finished.

Comment: Thanks for reply Hans. I simply want it to print the file's checksum using hex system e.g. 92e362f0 .

Comment: Then don't use %c, use %x.

Comment: i'm using %x in calculateChecksum function to 'cast' long to my char array. %c is used only to print the char array in main function

Comment: A C string must be zero-terminated, you are forgetting to copy the 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `calculateChecksum` is kind of mis-named, and also works the wrong way.

- You do not correctly check if `fread_s()` has really read all of the requested bytes. (Maybe I'm wrong here...)
- You are missing the terminating NUL byte after the string.
- You do not `free(buffer)`, so you have a memory leak.

If these conditions are fulfilled, you can do

```
printf("%s", hex);
```

in the `main()` function.

However, you do things much too complicated.

I would do

```
void calculateChecksum(char * filename, unsigned long * crc32){
    FILE *file;
    fopen_s(&file, filename, "rb");
    size_t size = fsize(filename);
    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    // TODO: If (!buffer) -> bail out.
    size_t td, crsr=0;
    do {
        rd = fread_s(buffer+crsr,size-crsr,size-crsr,1,file);
        if (rd > 0) crsr += rd;
    } while (rd > 0 && crsr < size)
    fclose(file);

    *crc32=CRC32(size,buffer);
    free(buffer);
}
```

This gives the caller the CRC32 directly as an `unsigned long` which directly can be printed using `printf("%08lx", crc32)`.

(BTW, it might be nicer to enhance your `CRC32()` to take the init value for the CRC as 3rd parameter. In this case, a blockwise calculation of the CRC would be possible.)